# Does XFCE4's panel support the indicator-application menu?

Tags: indicator, appmenu, xfce, xfce-panel

Does xfce4-panel currently have a support for global menu , not the gnome2-globalmenu project , but the indicator's appmenu , which runs well on gnome-panel.

I installed gnome-panel on xubuntu , but the indicator menu won't show on xfce4-panel.

Comment: @UriHerrera: he's referring to something else; the application menu that you find in Unity, not the indicator area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it could, but it currently is only written to load very specific indicators.  All of the indicators are basically the same, except the appmenu and application ones use the dynamic adding and removal feature, which I believe the XFCE applet doesn't yet support.  It's just a matter of someone writing that code :-)

Comment: it's being quiet long , i submitted a bug report , and may work on this later myself , thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea (I'm not sure if it works, I haven't tested):

- install `xfce4-xfapplet-plugin` and `indicator-applet-appmenu`
- add the XfApplet to your Xfce panel
- right click and choose 'Properties' and select the appmenu applet

For more information on the XfApplet plugin:
http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-xfapplet-plugin

Comment: Tried this before , i couldn't see indicator-applet-appmenu in xfapplet , however , i worked this out myself: http://opendesktop.org/content/show.php?content=146102